# Conditionally concatenate strings within a groupby aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which I need to group by on single field and aggregate on multiple fields. As part of aggregate, I need to concatenate a string column values in a sorted order conditionally.

**Input:**

```
SYSTIME             TT  REC TABLE   cat_a   cat_b   cat_c
01/11/2019 00:00    2   102 A       1       0       0
01/11/2019 00:00    2   103 B       1       0       0
01/11/2019 00:00    2   150 C       0       1       0
01/11/2019 00:01    3   200 B       1       0       0
01/11/2019 00:01    3   150 A       1       0       0
01/11/2019 00:01    3   104 D       0       0       1
01/11/2019 00:02    4   200 F       1       0       0
01/11/2019 00:02    5   250 A       1       0       0
01/11/2019 00:02    2   120 C       0       1       0
01/11/2019 00:02    3   150 E       1       0       0
```

**Output expected:**

```
SYSTIME             TT  REC TABLE   cat_a   cat_b   cat_c
01/11/2019 00:00    2   355 A;B     2       1       0
01/11/2019 00:01    3   454 A;B     2       0       1
01/11/2019 00:02    5   520 A;E;F   3       1       0
```

I have the following code:

`df_table_acc=df.groupby(['SYSTIME'],as_index=False).agg({'TT' : 'max','REC' : 'sum','TABLE': ';'.join, 'cat_a': 'sum', 'cat_b': 'sum', 'cat_c': 'sum'})`

The issue is with string concatenation, I want to concatenate TABLE values where cat_a=1 and also sorted order.
Currently I am getting A;B;C for minute 00:00 but expect only A;B where cat_a=1

Is there a way to add condition to the join function?

P.S: I am new to python, I did see similar questions but I want specifically to add condition inside an agg function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a way to do this within `agg` so if anyone does please do say.

However it's easily done outside of `agg`, with:

```
df_table_acc=df.groupby(['SYSTIME'],as_index=False).agg(    #Remove TABLE from first agg
            {'TT' : 'max','REC' : 'sum', 'cat_a': 'sum', 'cat_b': 'sum', 'cat_c': 'sum'})
df_table_acc = pd.merge(df_table_acc, df[df['cat_a']>0].copy().groupby(['SYSTIME'],as_index=False).agg(
            {'TABLE':';'.join}),how='left',on='SYSTIME')
```

This was edited for indexing issues. We are now using `merge` on `SYSTIME` to make sure the `TABLE` matches the `SYSTIME`

Alternatively, by changing the data, with a bit of cleanup afterwards (EDIT: fixed this part and added better separation)

```
import re
df['TABLE'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['TABLE'] if x['cat_a']>0 else '', axis=1)
df_table_acc=df.groupby(['SYSTIME'],as_index=False).agg(
            {'TT' : 'max','REC' : 'sum','TABLE': ';'.join, 
             'cat_a': 'sum', 'cat_b': 'sum', 'cat_c': 'sum'})
df_table_acc.TABLE = df_table_acc.TABLE.apply(lambda x: re.sub(';+',';',x).strip(';'))
#Quick explanation: the re part avoids having repeat ";" eg: "A;;C;D;;G" -> "A;C;D;G"
#The strip removes outside strings eg: ";A;B;" -> "A;B"
```

Make sure you don't need the `TABLE` column for anything else before using the second method, or use a dummy column like `TABLE2` or something.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Eisenberg I tried your first option and it works partially. But there is another issue, may this wasn't covered in the sample data. I need the TABLE column blank for rows where cat_a=0.

Comment: No problem! If this solved your issue, you can accept the answer (beneath the voting button)

Comment: Partly the issue now is when you filter on cat>1 and groupby, the timeseries will only have rows where cat_a>1 so when adding new column TABLE in second step doesn't fit to the original DF size.

Comment: Option 2 should work through that issue - I'm editing to add a reindex.

Comment: Both edited to work for your situation! Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks @JimEisenberg , merge works perfectly well and fits the df size.

Answer (score 0):

you problem can be solved by filtering your data before applying groupby and agg

function.Just add `df=df[df['cat_a']==1].sort_values('TABLE')` before using this code

df_table_acc=df.groupby(['SYSTIME'],as_index=False).agg({'TT' : 'max','REC' : 'sum','TABLE': ';'.join, 'cat_a': 'sum', 'cat_b': 'sum', 'cat_c': 'sum'})